# What was the first monster motivated by the need to replace worn-out or damaged body parts?

Tags: history-of, horror, jeepers-creepers

At least as far as movies are concerned, I do not think I have encountered in my watching experience a monster  similar to the one in *Jeepers Creepers*, that is motivated by the need to replace worn-out or damaged body parts.

This accounts even for its reason for deliberately frightening its potential victims.

This body-part replacement also provided a scene (the javelin/head scene) that was I thought was pretty impressive.

Seems to me the closest ideas are found in *The Thing* and maybe *I was a Teenage Frankenstein* but in the former, the idea is pretty different and in the latter, it is not nearly as explored.

What was the first movie or story with such a monster?

If someone can actually find even a self-published story that predates *Jeepers Creepers*, that would be of interest.

Comment: Since your question specifies "monster", I'm not going to post this as an answer, but in 1987, Mark Waid established a similar motivation for the super-villain Vandal Savage in the Flash comic book series. In order to sustain his immortality, Savage sought out his blood descendants whenever he needed an organ replacement.

Comment: @AllenR.Brady: Interesting although I do think "monster" is important here. You reminded me of the liver monster from X-Files which in a way was motivated by a similar need. X-Files predated JC.

Comment: This seems to be an (albeit quite interestingly-worded) 'list' question.

Comment: @Valorum, I get nothing in tvtropes (though I’m no expert there), so eating to replace worn/lost parts probably isn’t common enough to create a "list" (although it feels like it should be!). I guess that means that this question is really "what was the first (movie?) example of eating to replace? Was it Jeepers Creepers?". An edit from releseabe might clarify?

Comment: The problem with "are there any" list questions is that there's nothing to stop me writing a two-line fanfic, publishing it to the internet and then answering "yes"

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question to make it more of an "history of the trope" one. If you disagree with anything I edited, feel free to edit further :)

Comment: @Valorum I agree "are there any" questions are problematic ("first instance" ones are a way better fit IMHO) but I don't think I'll be telling you anything new about [them having been voted as receivable on meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1490/98028). 'til the votes on that change (if they ever), well, teeth grinding.

Comment: There was a monster in one of Jim Butcher's books, which I assume was based on existing mythology, that built itself out of the bones of its victims.  Not quite on-point, but close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marvel's character [Terror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terror_Inc.) had a similar power. When he needed to run quickly, he would tear off the legs a sprinter and attach them as his own, when he needed upper body strength, he would rip off the arms of a weight lifter (there are obvious problems with this but, comics).

Terror was created in 1988 but didn't get his own comic until 1992. He has never appeared in the MCU as far as I know.